# Machine Learning With Keywords

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, artificial-intelligence

So I am fairly new to machine learning and have a few questions about keywords. Right now I'm trying to make a machine learning model using some movie data that I have previously collected (The Data is made of 4 attributes one beeing keywords which describe the movie). Nonetheless, some movies have more keywords than others for (example: Spiderman's keywords would be superhero, spider, fight etc...) each movie has from 50 to 400 keywords, therefore I wanted to ask you if I should include each keyword as a separate attribute or should I just add all of them under Keywords and separate them with commas.

To better illustrate my point here is two examples:

**Including Movie Keywords as sperate Attributes**
[image: Table with movie Keyword as seperate attribute]

**Including Movie Keyword as one attribute**

[image: Table with movie Keyword as one attribute]

Thank you very much in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't really want either one of the approaches you suggested. I'm assuming you want your learning method to be able to compare/classify different movies using the keywords. Let's look at the problems with the suggested approaches:

- In the first approach you suggest 'ordered' keywords (i.e. keyword1, keyword2, etc.), but what if for example the order of *Superhero* and *Fight* switches, we get a different feature vector even though we have the same keywords (see table below)? This is not what we want, the order of the keywords shouldn't matter!

  ```
             |   Keyword1     Keyword2
   ------------------------------------
   Movie A   |  Superhero     Fight
   Movie B   |  Fight         Superhero
  ```
- Moving on, in the second approach you suggest to use all the keywords in a list. This way, only movies with the exact same keywords will be considered the same. Again, this isn't really ideal for comparing movies. If movie A shares 49 keywords with movie B, but has one different keyword, the learning method should be able to incorporate this information and say the movies are very much alike, rather than saying they are nothing alike.

Instead, you probably want to define the keywords themselves as features/attributes. This way both abovementioned problems can be handled, since the order doesn't matter and we can still learn from individual keywords. Your dataset of keywords would then look something like:

```
          |   Superhero     Fight     StackOverflow    ...
------------------------------------------------------------
Movie A   |      1            1            0           ...
Movie B   |      1            1            1           ...
```

indicating which keywords are present in which movie(s). This way, movies can easily be compared by almost any learning method. Note that I used binary values here to simply indicate presence/absence of the keyword, but -depending on the learning method- other representations can be used as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here the concept of lemmatizing will come in the picture, try to replace the similar keywords with the same name, for example, superhero, fight, can be replaced as **action** keyword and Dance, Music etc can come under **others** Genre. Try to minimize the keywords as much as possible and then create separate columns for each keyword. I hope you get my point.